# Do both alter and ref-set update the STM tree in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, stm

I am using refs everywhere in my Clojure code and then I realised I was using `ref-set` everywhere. Does this destroy the history of changes in the STM? Or should I be using `alter` only and `ref-set` to intialise the ref?

I am not sure if the difference is merely syntactical and `alter` ends up calling `ref-set` anyway. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(alter aref f arg1 ... argn)
```

is basically the same as

```
(ref-set aref (f @aref arg1 ... argn))
```

Similar for atoms with `reset!` and `swap!`.

Comment: I thought swap! was threadsafe and reset! wasn't, or am I mistaken?

Comment: The whole point of STM is to solve concurrency issues, all the functions you mentioned are meant to be thread safe.

Comment: @skuro. Ok, thanks for confirming that reset! and swap! are threadsafe